# check if page is already opened and Send parameter to it

Tags: asp.net, html, web-services, browser

How can I check if an asp.net/html page is already opened, and if it is, send a parameter and not open it again, and if it isn't opened, open it and send the parameter as usual..
What I want to do is: I have an asp.net page which execute a specific functionality and has status line to show to the user, I want to display the status line in another page (let's call it 'statuspage'), but because the status is changed many times I don't want to open the statusPage again and again.

How can I implement Thanks.

Comment: the downvote is not mine; do you have some code that you have tried or you want someone here to point you in the right big-picture-type direction?

Comment: I don't have code,I want someone to point me. but now I am checking something I found, I'll try it.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to open the new status window [using a custom name](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp).
Any subsequently windows opening calls should refresh the already created window.